# looping through table rows and executing jquery ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to execute this code:

```
    var table = document.getElementById("tab");
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
       //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
       let idd = row.cells[1].textContent;
       
       if(idd != 'Id' && idd != '') {
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/numordiniperiodoagenti",
                data: {id : idd, start: sstart, end: eend},
                success: function(response){
                    row.cells[10].textcontent = 'p'; //or response as it should be
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

But it seems that `row` is inaccessible inside this `ajax` call.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Post your html markup too. Also, why are you mixing jquery and vanilla JS?

Comment: Your `row` variable changes with each iteration, so in the success: callback it's already changed.  Move the `row` to inside the for loop and you'll be ok.

Comment: This should explain it all: [how do javascript closures work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111111#111111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since scope of your variable `row` is only inside the `for` loop, the ajax's callback function is another scope, so you could not access variable `row` inside the ajax's callback. To solve this issue, you could define other variable inside callback function, then assign `row` value to that new variable.

```
var table = document.getElementById("tab");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
   let idd = row.cells[1].textContent;
   
   if(idd != 'Id' && idd != '') {
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/numordiniperiodoagenti",
            data: {id : idd, start: sstart, end: eend},
            success: function(response){
                var target_row = row; 
                target_row.cells[10].textcontent = 'p'; //or response as it should be
            }
        });
    }
}
```